# HTML in webpack bundle. Why?

Tags: angularjs, angular, build, webpack, bundle

Good day,
I'm building and angular 2 app based off of this [starter pack](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). I'm trying to get a handle on what our build process will look like. I noticed when running:

```
npm run build:prod    
npm run server:prod
```

That html is located within the bundle file.In large applications this bundle file could be upwards 4-5mb or more. This could be a problem for mobile access. And that seems counter intuitive to the angular 2 approach.

Is this correct build for a large applications?
Shouldn't the HTML files be loaded as needed rather than all at once?

Perhaps I have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah basically that's what Webpack does. It **bundles** everything. Having your output file ~4MB is very likely to happen. What you need is to separate the file into **chunks**. Using the common chunk plugin this way you'll be able to bring let's say all your third-party libraries into one chunk.

Secondly, you can break the file further into more chunks then load them asynchronously.

you can find more about this in the [link](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html).

Comment: Webpack documentation is crap. I know how to generate the files using the plugin, but I do not know how to implement it in an angular 2 app. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any examples using Angular 2, I have work only with React and Vue.js. But the principle should be the same. You can add the `require.ensure` in your routes for example or in your `html`, then whenever you navigate to a particular route, it loads only the assets linked to that page. Makes sense?